# CreateRemoteThread fails on Windows7 64bit for 32bit applications

Tags: c, windows-7-x64, 32-bit, dll-injection, createremotethread

I have a code which injects a dll to a process. The process which executes the injection function is always in the same architecture (x86 or x64) as the injected process. But for some reason, the CreateRemoteThread function call fails on Win7 64 bit OS, when the injecting and injected processes are of x86 architecture. Surprisingly, when the OS is Win10 64bit. 32 bit processes work fine. The code also works well for Win7 64 bit with 64 bit processes, and for Win7 32 bit with 32 bit processes.

I've looked over the internet for a possible cause and all I could find is that in Win7 there are sometimes issues with process sessions. I don't think this is the case since both the injecting and injected processes are "user" sessions.

When running GetLastError() I get 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)

This is my injection function:

```
    DWORD Inject(DWORD PID, const char *dllname)
    {
        HANDLE hThread = NULL;
        BOOL writeSucceed = false;
        int cch = 0;

        cout << "Injector.dll : Injecting " << dllname << " to " << PID << endl;
        DWORD hLibModule;

        HMODULE hKernel32 = GetModuleHandle (TEXT ("Kernel32"));
        void *hProcess = OpenProcess (PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION |
                                      PROCESS_VM_WRITE, false, PID);  

        cch = strlen (dllname) + 1;

        void *pLibRemote = VirtualAllocEx (hProcess, NULL, cch, MEM_COMMIT,
            PAGE_READWRITE);

        writeSucceed = WriteProcessMemory (hProcess, pLibRemote, (void *) dllname, cch, NULL);

        hThread = CreateRemoteThread (hProcess, NULL, 0,
                                            (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)
                                            GetProcAddress (hKernel32,
                                            "LoadLibraryA"),
                                            pLibRemote, 0, NULL);

        WaitForSingleObject (hThread, INFINITE);
        GetExitCodeThread( hThread, &hLibModule );
        CloseHandle (hThread);

        VirtualFreeEx (hProcess, pLibRemote, sizeof (dllname), MEM_RELEASE);

        hThread = CreateRemoteThread (hProcess, NULL, 0,
                                     (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) GetProcAddress (hKernel32,
                                     "FreeLibrary"),
                                     (void *) hLibModule, 0, NULL);
        WaitForSingleObject (hThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle (hThread);
        return 0;
    }

Is there some special treatment I should do in code for Windows 7?
```

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` give when `CreateRemoteThread` fails?

Comment: @GauravSehgal I edited the post. The GetLastError() method returns 5.

Comment: `5` means `ACCESS DENIED`, what process are you trying to inject in? Check with different processes (may be running with lower privileges).

Comment: @GauravSehgal I am injecting on many kinds of processes, but mainly testing on a java application. I run as administrator. I think this is not the case since When running the exact same java in 64 bit mode, it all works fine.

Comment: It has to be something related to the 32-64 mismatch. Double check the processes and the dll you try to inject are of same architecture. Also keep in mind wow64 redirection, check with procmon to identify if some dll or its dependent dlls are getting accessed from 64 bit location(system32).

Comment: So I have made some changes to isolate the issue. I have created a very simple injected dll code which only prints "I am inside!", and I switched from java to a simple C console application with no code except getChar() to keep the console open. Still using the injection function above. I am still using the code above to inject, and no change. This question has been previously asked with no answer:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8257aa1c-de97-4c47-9bf9-ca74c3d6fc8a/createremotethread-returning-access-denied?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I had to add `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` to the `OpenProcess` flags. This was very tricky, since if you don't include this flag, it will still work everywhere except the case of Win7 64bit OS and 32bit application.